# Как получить значение из класса без методов

Tags: javascript, классы

Как получить значение из класса без методов используя только конструктор
Пример кода -

```
class Value {
  constructor() {
    /*
    код который бы вернул число
    */
  }
}
let result = new Value();
console.log(result /*Выводит например 3*/);
```

Comment: конструктор ничего не может возвращать

Comment: Что вы хотите таким образом достичь? Почему именно такой вид интересует?

Comment: Это условие задачи , нашел подобную задачу при проверки знаний по javascript при собеседовании https://pikabu.ru/page/interview/jobseeker/?t=frontend , первый assert , использовал все свои знания и так и не понял как возможно пройти это задание , мне кажется условия для прохождения невозможны.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Как-то так:

```js
class JobSeeker {
    i = -1;
    valueOf() {
        return this.i = this.i + 2;
    }
}

let inst = new JobSeeker();
console.log(
    inst == 1 && inst == 3 && inst == 5
);
```

Comment: Работает! А можно вкратце объяснить почему так работает код ?

Comment: Вкратце не получится. Вот статья об этом https://learn.javascript.ru/object-toprimitive

Comment: кстати, прочёл статью и заменил toString в ответе на valueOf. Так правильнее, потому что при конвертации в Number сначала проверяется valueOf, а уже потом toString(). Ну и toString() должен строку возвращать, а не чёрти-что.

Answer (score 0):

Можно вернуть либо ссылку на текущий объект, либо новый объект.

Вернёт объект `Value`:

```js
class Value {
  constructor (name){
     this.name = name;
     // Аналогично отработает без return
     return this.name;
  }
}

// Деструктуризация 
const {name} = new Value('Ivan');

console.log(name);
```

Вернёт новый объект:

```js
class Value {
  constructor (name){
     this.name = name;
     return {name};
  }
}

const {name} = new Value('Ivan');

console.log(name);
```

***Примитив вернуть нельзя.*** [Аналогичный вопрос](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3350215/what-is-returned-from-a-constructor).

Comment: Задача стояла именно не используя методы вернуть значение, если это не возможно вопрос исчерпан.

Comment: @ArtemPilipchuk подпраивил

Comment: Форшмак №2 создает видимость что что-то возвращает. А вообще - всё это Форшмак))

Comment: @СергейМишин удалил)) Кроме последнего варика, но это не ответ на вопрос.

Comment: @СергейМишин сам вопрос очень странный, конструктор служит для инициализации начального состояния.

Comment: Ну вот и ответ должен быть - "никак")

Comment: @СергейМишин можно, обновил ответ.

Comment: Что делает `return {name};` в первом примере?

Comment: @Igor подправил ответ. Второй пример возвращает новый объект с переданным в конструктор значением.

Comment: Что в 1-ом, что во 2-ом примере можно спокойно не писать `return` будет тоже самое, потому что по итогу не конструктор возвращает имя, а магия заключается в строке `{name}`, где происходит деструктуризация объекта `var {name} = {name:'Ivan', test:'Привет'};`

Comment: Это условие задачи , нашел подобную задачу при проверки знаний по javascript при собеседовании pikabu.ru/page/interview/jobseeker/?t=frontend , первый assert , использовал все свои знания и так и не понял как возможно пройти это задание , мне кажется условия для прохождения невозможны